# Faulting module name: gdiplus.dll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi, windows-server-2016

Error:

```
Faulting application name: Keaton.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5c3baa06
Faulting module name: gdiplus.dll, version: 10.0.14393.2665, time stamp: 0x5c060d0f
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000396ec
Faulting process id: 0xd0b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4bdc0bec33894
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.14393.2665_none_f6793c4ef24ff589\gdiplus.dll
```

Background:

I have written a c# WinForms application in VS2017.

I have recently had to move this application from W7 X64 to a Server 2016 VM.

I am getting the above problem quite regularly after the move (It never crashed previously after 5+years of use and now it is crashing 6+ times per day).

The application is a click-once application on a production server.

This application creates multiple forms at certain time intervals for end users to view (sometimes 10-15 forms may be loaded up at any given point, sometimes 5 or 6 simultaneously).

These forms have a countdown timer - So they are only visible for perhaps 3 minutes and then they are destroyed. In another few minutes, another 4 or 5 might pop up again. Countdown on forms 3 minutes again. Destroyed. Rinse and repeat.

The forms themselves have;

A couple of PictureBox controls(which load a bitmap), a few labels, 5 or 6 datagridview controls, 1 TabPage Control, countdown timer (label which just decrements time and displays how much longer the form is visible for),a timer control.

Nothing crazy or graphically intense (when compared to gaming/rendering etc)

I suspect it's the creation of these new forms that is causing this. Something is not quite gelling with this gdiplus.dll

The problem I have is this app needs to run 24/7 without issue - and it is now not. I do have an overwatch system in place that sends SMS's to my phone indicating failure - but it's not ideal and does not address the core issue.

Comment: I assume that you've verified that the server itself is fully patched and updated?

Comment: Also, check task manager to see if you're leaking GDI objects. (You'll need to add the GDI objects column)

Comment: Acquire a crash dump and analyze it. Your suspicion won't work unless you have some proof.